# FatalErrorException: Class not found - Laravel

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, laravel-4

I am working on a laravel project and would like to retrieve data from a server (postgresql). I have the class webmaster_tool in my Model folder but every time i try to call it with Eloquent i get this error:

**Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_ERROR)**
**Class 'webmasters_tool' not found**

This is my Controller:

```
 <?php
 /*Controller*/
 class WebmastersController extends BaseController {
     public function index() {
        $webmasters_tools = webmasters_tool::all();
        return View::make('webmasters_tools.index', ['webmasters_tools'     => $webmasters_tools]);
     }
 }
```

My Model:

```
 <?php
 //Modell
 class webmasters_tool extends Eloquent {
 }
```

My route:

```
 Route::get('/webmasters_tools', 'WebmastersController@index');
```

I would really appreciate if someone helped me out here.

Comment: Where have you saved the file containing the `webmasters_tool` class, and have you tried running `composer dump-autoload` in the terminal before reloading the page?

Comment: @wolfemm, sorry, that was a typo in my question. The class name is webmasters_tool (not webmasters_tools) and it is saved in my Models folder. Laravel is installed on the server and i cannot run composer from my station. I'll probably have to get the server admin to do that for me and thats a lot of red tape.

Comment: I'm betting that command will fix it. Your class is in a folder that composer already autoloads, so you just need to have composer regenerate the autoloader.

Comment: What is the name of your model file?

Comment: The name of my model file is the same as the class name: webmasters_tool.

Comment: @wolfemm, the problem persists even after composer dump-autoload.

Comment: @TonyOkoth Strange. Do you have access to `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` within the project? If so, does a line containing "/models/webmasters_tool.php" exist within `autoload_classmap.php`? This will let us know for sure whether or not the class is being autoloaded.

Comment: I also recommend renaming both the file and class to pascal case. So the file would be named `WebmastersTool.php` and the class `WebmastersTool`. This is the standard, and composer may be making assumptions based on it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're missing the use declaration:

```
use App\webmasters_tool;
```